# Exporting Flare animation

Tags: flutter, flare

Flare animation won't display on the screen. 
I'm using:

```
Container(
              height: 300.0,
              width: 300.0,
              child: FlareActor('checkmarkone.flr',
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
              ),
            ),
```

When I'm running the app I get this message in the run console:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: checkmarkone.flr
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      FlareCacheAsset.load (package:flare_flutter/flare_cache_asset.dart:31:20)
#2      Cache.getAsset (package:flare_flutter/cache.dart:56:15)
#3      cachedActor (package:flare_flutter/flare_cache.dart:35:16)
#4      FlareRenderBox.loadFlare (package:flare_flutter/flare_render_box.dart:322:35)
#5      FlareActorRenderObject.coldLoad (package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart:322:20)
#6      FlareRenderBox.load (package:flare_flutter/flare_render_box.dart:272:7)
#7      FlareRenderBox.attach (package:flare_flutter/flare_render_box.dart:115:7)
#8      AbstractNode.adoptChild (package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart:132:13)
#9      RenderObject.adoptChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1238:11)
#10     RenderObjectWithChildMixin.child= (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2905:7)<…>
```

I appreciate all suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `checkmarkone.flr` file in your assets folder, then add it to your pubspec.yaml file

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - checkmarkone.flr
```

and then, run `flutter packages get` command to update the dependencies. Finally, do a cold restart of your project

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **pubspec.yaml** file and ensure that the file `checkmarkone.flr` has been added/loaded correctly.

Eg.

**pubspec.yaml**

```
... (more on top)
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
   - assets/checkmarkone.flr # Add it here
... (more on bottom)
```

Now wait for the flutter task (updating packages) to finish, then try loading the Flare animation using the asset path added above in your screen / widget via hot restart.

**widget.dart**

```dart
Container(
  height: 300.0,
  width: 300.0,
  child: FlareActor('assets/checkmarkone.flr',
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
  ),
),
```

**Further reading**

- https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images